# How can I conduct a search, using a partial string, to search a list of objects with string parameters and find the object I'm looking for in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, search

What I'm creating is a type of store. I can add product objects to said store(also an object) with multiple parameters, including a title(string), description(string), and product_number(integer).

I would like to create a function that takes as a parameter a string that could be used to search the title and description parameters of all product objects in the inventory(list), find matches(partial and full, it doesn't matter in this case), append those matching objects to a list called search_results, sort them in ascending order by their product_number, and return them to the user.

```
    class Product:

        def __init__(self, code, title, desc, price, quantity):
            self._code = code
            self._title = title
            self._desc = desc
            self._price = price
            self._quantity = quantity

        def decrease_quantity(self):
            self._quantity = self._quantity - 1

        def get_product_code(self):
            return self._code

        def get_product_title(self):
            return self._title

        def get_product_price(self):
            return self._price

        def get_product_quantity(self):
            return self._quantity

        def get_product_desc(self):
            return self._desc

    class Store:

        def __init__(self):
            self._store_inventory = []
            self._store_members = []

        def product_search(self, product_keyword):
            search_results = []
            for product in self._store_inventory:
                if product_keyword in product.get_product_title():
                    search_results.append(product)
                elif product_keyword in product.get_product_desc():
                    search_results.append(product)
                else:
                    return "Not Found"
            search_results.sort()
            return search_results
```

This is what I have so far.

The main problem I have(there are a few, i know) is that I cannot get the product_search function to work properly. That is, it always reverts the the "else" case and returns "Not Found", even when I give the exact case and spelling of the product title.

What is it I'm doing wrong in that regard?

Comment: Leaving out the code for `Product()` makes it impossible to know what methods like `product.get_product_title()` return, which makes it impossible to tell why a comparison like `product_keyword in product.get_product_title()` doesn't work as expected. Confusion mainly arises when people have to guess at your code.

Comment: @Grismar apologies. Edit made.

Comment: That helps, but now the question becomes what are you using exactly as values for `title` and `desc` when you create a `Product()` - instead of a back and forth, perhaps follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to implement the function `__eq__` for the `product` class, according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details)

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression `x in y` is equivalent to `any(x is e or x == e for e in y)`.

The reason your `in` operator does not work because the `__eq__` function for the class not implemented so Python does not know how to compare your object instances (what properties to compare,...)

Read more about [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__)

Example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

class Bar:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.a == other.a
f1 = Foo(5)
f2 = Foo(5)
print("f1 == f2", f1 == f2)
fl = [f1,f2]
f3 = Foo(5)
print("f3 in fl", f3 in fl)

g1 = Bar(5)
g2 = Bar(5)
print("g1 == g2",g1 == g2)
gl = [g1,g2]
g3 = Bar(5)
print("g3 in gl", g3 in gl)
```

Output:

```
f1 == f2 False
f3 in fl False
g1 == g2 True
g3 in gl True
```